# Checking whether row values is coming as STRING in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Here I am using a Copy data activity. I need to update string values as Null in my sink table. How Can I achieve this in azure data factory.
Source: json data
Target: sql table

Pls Note: I cannot use Dataflows  since I am using self hosted VM.

Comment: Hi @Being Real, could you please confirm your source and target both are on prem?

Comment: @BhanunagasaiVamsi
 Only source is in onprem,also source i am getting as json data

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in data flows. To connect to on-prem source with data flows, you can use this method with the Azure IR, no need for a self-hosted IR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server

Comment: I cannot use Azure IR ,so cannot use dataflows

Comment: Why can you not use Azure IR?